# Calculating rolling sum of inflows with a base limit of 0

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, cumulative-sum

I am currently looking to calculate the rolling sum of inflows while ensuring I base my outflows to 0 and never allowing them to get negative. I am attempting to do this in a pyspark dataframe as the data cannot be converted into pandas due to its size.

The dataset looks like below(Mocked Sample) with the expected output seen in expected rolling:

df2 = spark.createDataFrame ([
['30-Jan-2019', -200] , ['30-Jun-2019', -100], ['30-Jan-2020',100], ['30-Jun-2020', 50], ['30-Jan-2021', 300],
['30-Jan-2021', -500], ['30-Jul-2021', 800], ['15-Sep-2021',-300]], ["transaction_date", "transaction_amount"])

```
df2 = df2.select(to_date(col ("transaction_date"), "dd-MMM-yyyy").alias('transaction_date'), 'transaction_amount')
```

There is a better representation of the dataset below:

[Excel Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J86e.png)

I've tried using the running sum technique and failed at it.

```
windowval = (Window.orderBy ('posting_date').rangeBetween (Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df2.withColumn('cum_sum', when(col('transaction_amount')>0,sum(col('net_sls')).over(windowval)).otherwise(0)).show()
```

I was able to achieve it programmatically in excel but unable to replicate it on pyspark as I was unable to use the output for the previous line.

[Image with Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im1Nr.png)

Google Collab Sheet for ease of reference: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ao9z165PRiUcj05f7cUZsvO0T-LpAHHX#scrollTo=-Urja7MyXSfJ

Comment: are you using the Azure databrick?

Comment: I'm currently running this on AWS within my org.